# Perché sono "la Moldava", "la Senna", "la Garonna"... al femminile?

Tags: etymology, articles, gender, proper-nouns

Questa domanda mi è venuta in mente ascoltando *la Moldava* di Bedřich Smetana su Rai Radio 3 Classica.

Se si tratta di fiumi, e "fiume" in italiano è maschile, perché non diciamo "il Moldava", "il Senna" o "il Garonna" come, ad esempio, "il Tevere", "il Po", "il Tago", "il Reno" o "il Danubio"?

Ci sono ragioni di tipo etimologico che avrebbero a che vedere con il genere di questi fiumi in una lingua straniera di origine, probabilmente parlata, magari in passato, in qualche zona in cui scorre il fiume?

So che in francese è "la Seine", immagino perché, per qualche ragione, provenga dell'espressione in francese "la rivière Seine". Qualcuno di voi saprebbe se "Vltava" in ceco è femminile? Non sono riuscita a trovare questa informazione.

Oppure si tratterebbe semplicemente di certa tendenza storica della lingua italiana ad attribuire genere femminile alle parole che finiscono in *-a*?

In catalano abbiamo anche alcuni nomi di fiumi che sono femminili, tra i quali appunto "la Garona" (in castigliano è invece "el Garona"). Secondo la spiegazione che si trova a [l'Optimot](https://aplicacions.llengua.gencat.cat/llc/AppJava/index.html?action=Principal&method=detall&input_cercar=noms+de+rius&numPagina=1&database=FITXES_PUB&idFont=12587&idHit=12587&tipusFont=Fitxes+de+l%27Optimot&numeroResultat=1&databases_avansada=&categories_avansada=&clickLink=detall&titol=Noms+de+rius%3A+masculins+o+femenins%3F+%2F+El+g%E8nere+dels+noms+dels+rius+%28hidr%F2nims%29+catalans&tematica=&tipusCerca=cerca.fitxes) (il servizio di consulenza linguistica della "Direcció General de Política Lingüística" della Generalità della Catalogna), si tratterebbe di espressioni in cui un nome femminile come, per esempio, "ribera" o "aigua", sarebbe sottinteso. Tutti i fiumi di nome femminile che appaiono sulla pagina dell'Optimot, però, scorrono almeno in parte in territori in cui si parla o si parlava catalano. Invece, i nomi di fiumi stranieri, perlomeno che io sappia, sono maschili: diciamo "el Sena" ed "el Moldava".

La mia domanda fa riferimento soltanto ai nomi di fiumi non italiani il cui nome derivi da una lingua parlata oggi o in passato all'estero (notate però che è una mia ipotesi che questo accada per la Senna, la Moldava o la Garonna): mi rendo conto che dare una spiegazione generale, cioè una spiegazione valida per tutti i nomi di fiumi, sulla ragione etimologica per cui il nome di un fiume italiano sia maschile ("il Sesia", per esempio) o femminile (come "la Trebbia") sia praticamente impossibile.

Comment: La mia fidanzata parla ceco e ha confermato che "Vltava" è femminile.

Comment: @DonHolgo Non conosco il ceco, ma sembra che anche il sostantivo "řeka" (fiume) sia femminile.

Comment: Anche in francese il Reno e il Rodano sono maschili.

Comment: “Qualcuno di voi saprebbe se "Vltava" in ceco è femminile? Non sono riuscita a trovare questa informazione.”
Certo, Vltava (come tutti i nomi che finiscono con a) in ceco è femminile invece Rýn (il Reno) è maschile.

Comment: * tendenza storica della lingua italiana ad attribuire genere femminile alle parole che finiscono in -a* Non solo italiana, è comune a tutte le lingue indoeuropee.

Comment: Non credo sia obbligatoria la concordanza di genere tra quello del sostantivo che definisce di un insieme con il genere degli elementi che lo compongono. Insieme: il fiume (maschile)
Elementi: La Moldava, La Dora Baltea, La Senna (femminili), ma anche il Tevere, il Po, il Don, il Danubio (maschile)... Insieme: la posata (femminile)
Elementi: il cucchiaio, il coltello (maschili); la forchetta (femminile) Insieme: il mobile Elementi: il tavolo, l'armadio, il comodino (maschile); la credenza, la sedia, la po

Answer (score 6):

> **Accademia della Crusca**
> Come l’etimologia dei nomi dei fiumi, che per lo più risalgono alla notte dei tempi, non di rado è incerta, così il loro genere grammaticale, potendo dipendere da vari fattori anch’essi ormai remoti, non è facile da giustificare. Un fiume, infatti, non si fonda su un genere “reale”, come avviene per gli esseri sessuati, ai quali è quasi sempre pacifico attribuire un maschile o un femminile; e nemmeno su elementi che possano esser ricondotti concettualmente all’uno o all’altro sesso.

[Fiumi femminili, fiumi maschili - Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/contenuti/fiumi-femminili-fiumi-maschili/69#:%7E:text=Sono%20maschili%2C%20come%20Fiume%2C%20i,Il%20Volga%2C%20Il%20Niagara%C2%BB.) (l'articolo è piuttosto lungo, ma penso valga la pena leggerlo)

> **@Charo**
> So che in francese è "la Seine", immagino perché, per qualche ragione, provenga dell'espressione in francese "la rivière Seine".

Per quanto riguarda la Senna, sembra accettato che debba il suo nome alla dea romana Sequana. I reperti trovati nei pressi delle sue fonti e raccolti nel Museo Archeologico di Digione lo attestano. Da qui l'uso del femminile.

Interessante il processo di "mascolinizzazione" avviato spesso da ambienti esterni allo scopo di regolarizzare e uniformare la lingua a dispetto della storia e dell’uso popolare. Quando la Piave diventò il Piave ci fu una mezza rivoluzione.

Comment: Grazie, @Giuseppe: ho aggiunto un chiarimento alla fine del corpo della domanda.

Answer (score -1):

Secondo un funzionario archeologo della Soprintendenza del Piemonte (dott. F. M. Gambari), il genere femminile dei fiumi è legato alla tradizione dell'area culturale celtica (ad esempio la Sesia, nel Vercellese, la Dora).